# Вывод элементов подсписков в обратном порядке

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Задание вывести вложенный список наоборот (каждый вложенный список в списке вывести наоборот).
Почему у меня на выводе вместо первого вложенного списка выдает `None`? Что я сделал не так? Или я вообще сделал задание не правильно изначально?

Вывод:

```
[None, [102, 7, 9], [105, 106, 102], [103, 98, 99, 100], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Код:

```
list1 = [[1, 7, 8], [9, 7, 102], [102, 106, 105], [100, 99, 98, 103], [1, 2, 3]]

for j in list1:
    list1[0] = j.reverse()



print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что функция `reverse()` - не возвращает новый список, она изменяет исходный.

Это значит, что в результате работы функции ее значение всегда будет `None`.

> Что можно сделать?

Можно просто не присваивать элементам вашего списка значения, а обойтись без этого:

```
list1 = [[1, 7, 8], [9, 7, 102], [102, 106, 105], [100, 99, 98, 103], [1, 2, 3]]

for j in list1:
    j.reverse()

print(list1)
```

Вывод

```
[[8, 7, 1], [102, 7, 9], [105, 106, 102], [103, 98, 99, 100], [3, 2, 1]]
```

**Дополнительно**

Суть вашего кода - применение к каждому элементу списка функции `reverse()`, для таких целей можно воспользоваться встроенной функцией `map()`, вот [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) на нее:

```
list1 = [[1, 7, 8], [9, 7, 102], [102, 106, 105], [100, 99, 98, 103], [1, 2, 3]]

list(map(list.reverse, list1))

print(list1)
```

Вывод

```
[[8, 7, 1], [102, 7, 9], [105, 106, 102], [103, 98, 99, 100], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Но в каком смысле второй вариант(дополнительный) - проще? Код выглядит больше и сложнее.

Comment: @umeliere отредактировал ответ. по сути - это просто более "питонячий" код, потому что логику цикла мы реализовываем одной строкой при помощи встроенной функции, бывают случаи, когда это позволяет десятки строк кода записать намного компактнее

Comment: лямбда здесь не требуется `list(map(list.reverse, list1))`

Comment: @АлексейР Спасибо за дельное замечание! дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой строчке:

```
list1[0] = j.reverse()
```

метод `reverse` не возвращает никакого результата, он просто переворачивает сам список `j`.

Поэтому нет смысла куда-то присваивать `j.reverse()` - это всегда будет `None`

Вместо этого надо писать так:

```
list1[0] = list(reversed(j))
```

При этом в вашем коде есть и другие ошибки.

Например, вы каждый раз новый перевёрнутый список записываете вместо одного и того же первого элемента.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через срезы и списковое включение:

```
list1 = [x[::-1] for x in list1]
```